# Solr Read Index Files

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am working with Solr and I feel interested in understanding all the nitty gritty details of the Solr Index. I am using Solrcloud and the index folder contains several files which includes:

```
_k.fdt -> field data            
_k.fnm -> fields           
segments_5
_k.fdx -> field index            
_k.si -> segment info             
...
```

They all look like binary/serialized object. I tried to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/jpountz/6461246) code to read the index file but failed with the following error. Can anyone help me on that?

```
public class Readfdt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final byte segmentID[];
        Path indexpath = Paths.get(
                "<solrhome>/example/cloud/node1/solr/gettingstarted_shard1_replica1/data/indexbackup");
        String indexfile = "_k.fdt";
        Codec codec = new Lucene54Codec();
        Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexpath);
        String segmentName = "_k";
        segmentID = new byte[StringHelper.ID_LENGTH];
        IOContext ioContext = new IOContext();
        SegmentInfo segmentInfos = codec.segmentInfoFormat().read(dir, segmentName, segmentID, ioContext.READ);
        System.out.println(segmentInfos);
    }
}
```

And the error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: file mismatch, expected id=0, got=2umd1rtwuv6lu48qbzywr533s (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="<solrhome>/example/cloud/node1/solr/gettingstarted_shard1_replica1/data/indexbackup/_k.si")))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeaderID(CodecUtil.java:266)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:86)
    at com.datafireball.Readfdt.main(Readfdt.java:29)
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum passed (13f6e228). possibly transient resource issue, or a Lucene or JVM bug (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="<solrhome>/example/cloud/node1/solr/gettingstarted_shard1_replica1/data/indexbackup/_k.si")))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:379)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:117)
        ... 1 more
```

In the end but not the least, I am new to Java generally and wondering what is the best practice to quickly locate the code to be able to locate the right class/code to deserialize any serialized object.

Comment: The format for the current index reader is [specified in the documentation for the codec package](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene54/package-summary.html#Overview), if you want to get into the actual details.

Comment: @MatsLindh there is helpful, however, do you know where I can get some sample code reading each of those file types?